# Repository problem:sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Tags: repository

I am trying to install php 8.3 on my ubutu 22.04. I am following the guide:

[Php 8.3 installation](https://php.watch/articles/php-8.3-install-upgrade-on-debian-ubuntu)

When I am executing the command:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

I am getting the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease
Err:10 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Err:24 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04 Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 23.212.72.84 80]
E: The repository 'http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64  InRelease' is no longer signed.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 18.04 Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: The error is with the Virtualbox repository.